# Flex/AIR: Sending email with embedded image.. how?

Tags: apache-flex, image, email, air

I'm making a Flex AIR application that will produce a giftcard from a webcam picture. This giftcard needs to be sent in an e-mail to a recipient provided in the program. Should I upload the picture to a server and use php to send the mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using SMTP Mailer, an ActionScript library for SMTP.  It supports attachments, so it should meet your needs.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27

Comment: nice, thanks man! this thing is awesome, working really good :)

Answer (score 3):

```
        var mailer:SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer("localhost",25);
        var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(photo.width,photo.height);
        myBitmap.draw(photo);
        var myEncoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
        var myCapStream:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode (myBitmap);
        var subject:String = "subject goes here";
        var content:String = "This is content";
        mailer.sendAttachedMail ( "noreply@nobody", toEmail.text,subject, content, myCapStream, "style.jpg");
```

I used [SMTPMailer 0.9](http://code.google.com/p/smtpmailer/downloads/detail?name=SMTPMailer%200.9.zip&can=2&q=) that is hosted in google code. 0.6 has a problem with image attachment.For email, "[Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)" is used to simulate the mail server.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the SMTP Mailer. The email is sent fine if there are no attachments, but if there is any attachment (text/pdf/jpg - anything) it fails with the message: 554 Suspicious message. Any ideas?

Comment: I used version 0.9, hosted on google code. No problem with attachments. The code I posted came from development. May be other factor caused the problem that you are facing.

Comment: I have pasted the entire code of my app - (101 lines only) here- http://pastebin.com/NS0zV40n - Please see if you can spot any problems. I am ready to tear out my hair.

Comment: I have no idea. I would like to help but I'm in the midst of public holidays. I'm really sorry.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate if you could check whenever you have the time. I am looking for the answer and will post here if I find any. Thanks

Comment: it gives me the following error: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2031: Socket Error.
 at emailTester()[C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Dan Naim\Sinagoga\Sinagoga\emailTester.as:20]
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()