# How to send email with Flex Exception

Tags: apache-flex

As I'm rolling out my Flex app to Beta I realized that I need to know about any exception that happens in Flex Side. But as it runs on users machines I don't get to see them.

Is there a way to make Flex send email every time an exception happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks possible with the help of some action script library:

[Sending Error Reports via Email from Flash, Flex, Air](http://www.quilix.com/node/41)

Comment: seems fine but I wasnt sure how to capture the log from the exception. So I want any exception to be emailed instead of me catching the exception is that possibl

Comment: if they aren't using a debug player, there won't be any stack to your exception. Other than that, look at the global exception handler

Comment: This looks interesting:   http://www.rialvalue.com/blog/2010/05/13/global-exception-or-error-handling-in-flex/ ... makes things a little more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try SMTPMailer.

[Flex/AIR: Sending email with embedded image.. how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900113/flex-air-sending-email-with-embedded-image-how/3536200#3536200)

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem in an internal Flex application.

Instead of automatically sending the email, we created a pop-up that contained a `mailto` link.  The link contained a email body that had the error included.

This may not work for you, but allows your users to choose if they submit the error to you or not, which can help prevent privacy issues.

This approach also allows you to communicate with your user and get more details or let them know when the problem is fixed.