# How to send e-mail with attachment using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, email

In my application I have to send e-mail with an attachment in ActionScript 3.0. I'm using Flash builder (Burrito). The target application is the Blackberry Playbook (using Adobe Air SDK)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex/AIR: Sending email with embedded image.. how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900113/flex-air-sending-email-with-embedded-image-how)

Answer (score 0):

<s>You cannot send email with only using Flash, you need some server side scripts to do this.</s> 
The easiest way *i know* is to create a simple php script and path there all necessary parameters. We have a lot of topics here on SO about sending mail from php. Look at right side of this page a "Related links" list ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266284/sending-an-e-mail-with-attachment-with-php-from-flex) could be especially interesting for you).

**UPDATE**

As was figured out by **soju** you can do this with socet connection to smtp server.

Comment: It is possible, with as3, using sockets and connect to a smtp server

Comment: anyway, I think it is much simpler to use a server side script :)

Comment: I believe he is looking for a way to access the native e-mail sending functionality, which afaik is not possible with AIR.