# mailto with attachments in Flex or AIR applications

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

How to forward attachment(for example image) from Flex or AIR application to email client?
For forwarding email address, body and subject, I use this:

```
var s:String = "";    
s+= "mailto:";
s+= g.text;               
s+= "?";
s+= "subject=" ;
s+= grup.text;
s+= "&";
s+= "body=";
s+= message.text;                                               
var url:URLRequest=new URLRequest(s);       

navigateToURL( url);
```

But I don't know what to do for attachment....
Please HELP!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex/AIR: Sending email with embedded image.. how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900113/flex-air-sending-email-with-embedded-image-how)

Answer (score 1):

mailto protocol does not support attachments.

http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-How-to-attach-a-local-file-to-an-email-with--URLRequest-from-AIR-p28091212.html